# Create Fn::GetAtt references between cloudformation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating custom cloudformation templates and I understand that you can use your outputs to call in parameters from other templates into other templates using the Fn::GetAtt feature.

Currently my VPC template has, for example;

```
"ParentVPC" : {    
    "Description" : "VPC ID",
    "Value" : { "Ref" : "VPC" }
},
"DBSubnet01" : {
    "Description" : "DB Subnet 01",
    "Value" : {"Ref": "DBSubnet01"}
}
```

So from my application template I'm wondering how I would call those in as parameters. I have tried;

```
"ParentVPC" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
     "Description" : "VPC of Parent"
 },
"DBSubnet01": {
    "Description" : "Reference to VPC DBSubnet01",
    "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
    "ConstraintDescription": "must be list of EC2 subnet ids"
}
```

Any suggestions welcomw

Answer (score 1):

In the template defining the VPC, create output values like this:

```
"Outputs" : {
    "ParentVPC" : {
        "Value" : {"Ref":"VPC"},
        "Description" : "VPC ID"
    },
    ...
}
```

Then, in the template using the VPC, create parameters like this:

```
"Parameters" : {
    "ParentVPC" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
    },
    ...
}
```

When creating a stack from this template, call `describe-stack` on the VPC-defining stack to get the output values, and pass them as parameters to `create-stack`.